# how to get list of file names from remote server using connect direct secure plus protocol in unix

Tags: linux, file-copy

how to get list of file names from remote server using connect direct secure plus protocol in unix..I know that we can get files ..but I just want filenames

Comment: What is "connect direct secure plus protocol in unix"? Have you read `https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/connect-direct/6.0.0?topic=security-connectdirect-secure-plus` ?

Answer (score 0):

Connect:Direct software is software that costs many thousands of $$$, then you have to pay many thousands of $$$ to get support. The op should be asking IBM.

However, the Connect:Direct software, with or without Secure Plus, does not allow directory listings. If you wish to get a list, the remote server will have to generate a listing to a file and allow you to pull that. This is for reasons of security.

And a bit of added info... C:D is mainly used in the financial industry to transfer files securely with non-repudiation. Where files are generated or stored may involve multiple institutions. They are never going to allow listings. Do you really want one bank to see what may be getting transferred to other banks?